# How to assign a array of a value to param in Smarty?

Tags: php, smarty

In my php code.

```
$version_config = array( 
    "list" => array(
        "123"
    ),
... other params
)   
$this->getView()->assign('version_config', $version_config);
$this->getView()->assign('version_list', $version_config['list']);
```

In my tpl code,

```
{assign var="version_list2" value="{$version_config.list}"}
```

`{$version_list2}` is a string values "Array" while `{$version_list2}` is an array. Do I need some more operations to encode `{$version_list2}` to an array?

Comment: Instead of quotes ( `value=" ... "` ) , try `[` and `]`  ( `value=[ ... ]` ).  Also see [Defining arrays section](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.syntax.variables.tpl) and you will notice they are more like json notation for the value defining.

Comment: Your suggestion is worked. Thanks. But by adding [] makes the value become array(array()), Just remove{} is ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The double quotes are converting `$version_config.list` array to string `"Array"` just as `"{$version_config['list']}"` in PHP.

Also, there is no need for curly braces in the value. Simply pass the variable in the `value` parameter:

```
{assign var="version_list2" value=$version_config.list}
```